# Poisson brackets of angular momentum

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

So I'm trying to simplify this Poisson bracket of angular momentum vectors: {$L_1,L_2$}

Where $L=r \times p$

I know that $L_1=r_2p_3-r_3p_2$ and $L_2=r_3p_1-r_1p_3$ (I can easily derive this from cross product of the position $r$ and momentum $p$ vectors). But then I get a Poisson bracket$$\{r_2p_3-r_3p_2, r_3p_1-r_1p_3\}$$ and I don't know how to proceed to break it up from there. Do I distribute or do I use $\{fg,h\}=\{f,h\}g+f\{g,h\}$ property? Any help's appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to distribute to get four different Poisson brackets, and then use the expansion property you cited to simplify them. Luckily, most of these brackets will vanish; this is obvious if you already know the pairwise brackets $\{r_i,r_j\}$, $\{p_i,p_j\}$, and $\{r_i,p_j\}$.

Comment: I get brackets like $\{r_2,r_3p_1\}p_3+r_2\{p_3,r_3p_1\}$. What do I do with these? The expansion property only works if there are two terms multiplied together in the first component of the Poisson bracket.

Comment: Actually, there's an analogous result when they're in the second. The easiest way to see this is from the antisymmetry of the bracket: $\{A,B\}=-\{B,A\}.$ @TomD1.

Comment: OK, thanks. This calculation yields 16 terms (most of which are zero), is there an easier way of doing this problem?

Comment: @TomD1 Well, each of the four terms obtained upon distribution ends up yielding exactly one nonzero bracket, so things simplify more than you might realize. One could instead use index notation instead but this creates its own difficulties. Finally, this kind of problem is something to get used to, as very similar computations appear in quantum mechanics.

Comment: I'm getting $-r_2p_1-p_2r_1$ as my final answer. Is that right?

Comment: One of the minus signs should be a plus so that $\{L_1,L_2\}$ is just $L_3$ (with that sign, I think). @TomD1